# Configure firewall for Mastodon bot

Tags: ufw, mastodon, mastodon-py

I have made this bot for Mastodon with mastodon.py:

https://github.com/aitormendez/loro/blob/main/loro.py

The bot listens to mentions and responds to them. I have it running at home on a raspberry pi. I'm trying to configure ufw (firewall) but when I activate it the bot stops working.

What ports should I leave open for the bot? As far as I know, there is no need to open any listening port, but if I activate ufw the bot stops working.

This is the ufw configuration:

```
aitor@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo ufw status
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```